# question about adding another column to a sql statement

Tags: sql

i am starting with this table:

[alt text http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8396/imagezx.png](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8396/imagezx.png)

```
SELECT [Lab Occurrence Form].[Practice Code], [Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)], Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]) AS [CountOf1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]
FROM [Lab Occurrence Form]
WHERE ((([Lab Occurrence Form].[Occurrence Date]) Between [Forms]![By Number]![Text4] And [Forms]![By Number]![Text2]))
GROUP BY [Lab Occurrence Form].[Practice Code], [Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]
HAVING ((([Lab Occurrence Form].[Practice Code])<>"") AND ((Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]))<>0));
```

it selects 3 columns but i need to aggregate the comments and put it in the fourth column where the first two values are the same

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MySQL, take a look at GROUP_CONCAT().